# Java - Excel Import Dates and Numbers

Tags: java, excel, date, import-from-excel

I am currently facing a small problem.

I am trying to import numbers from an excel-file. While testing the import, I figured out that dates are NUMERIC values. And so, users can accidentally type in a date instead of a number.

Does anyone have a clue how to prevent from importing dates?

Thanks in advance!